# Data not appearing in plotly 3d scatterplot

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to render some data in a 3d scatterplot in plotly and none of it was showing up. I decided to try plotly's sample graph, but it's not working either:

```
library(plotly)

mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 0)] <- 'Automatic'
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 1)] <- 'Manual'
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, color = ~am, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E')) %>%
  add_markers() %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight'),
                     yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower'),
                     zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time')))
```

I get:

[image]

I'm using RStudio 1.0.143, and my version of R is 3.2.3. I've tried running this on a Windows 10 VM as well with the same result.

Comment: Try installing plotly from Github:  devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly"). However, the issue is described here: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1055

Comment: @ed_sans Do I have to/should I first uninstall the version I installed from `install.packages('plotly')`?

Comment: You could uninstall first the current version using remove.packages()

Comment: I always hate turning comments sections into troubleshooting back-and-forths, but I'm getting the error `Installation failed: cannot open file '/home/me/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/plotly/R/sysdata.rdb': No such file or directory
Warning message:
In eapply(ns_env(pkg), force, all.names = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation ` and I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises with the current version of plotly (4.7.0). I would suggest installing a previuos version of plotly and then run again your codes:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_version("plotly", version = "4.5.6", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoting for the effort, but see the comment I made in my question about installing and the error; it's possible that resolving it is outside the ken of this question, but until I fix it I seem to not be able to install anything with devtools

Comment: Try cleaning your workspace, then restart R-studio. Load the devtools package. Uninstall the old version of plotly and install the new one. Rerun your codes